# Reverse C++ lookup

Tags: c++, templates

I am a "C" programmer that knows just the tiniest bits of C++. I am having a look at some open source C++ code trying to understand some things that it is doing. I can work out most of it but sometimes there is syntax I don't recognise and I'd like to be able to "look up" the meaning of the syntax so I can read just enough to understand that bit of C++. But you can't just type a bunch of symbols into google - or whatever to find out the meaning in C++. Any suggestions of how I can do this in general?

The specific syntax I'm struggling with right now is the following:

```
void Blah<BOARD>::Generate(SgPoint p)
```

What is the significance of the `<BOARD>` in this context? What should I look up in order to understand it?

Comment: C++ is a little bit non-trivial for this kind of approach.

Comment: Actually, the easiest solution is what you just did: asking on SO.

Comment: @ereOn: Well, the answer currently voted to the top came in 8mins after Mick posted his question. Add to this a few minutes to compose the question and a few more to wait which one will be voted to the top, and every time he's stuck he'll have to wait 15-20mins. How often, do you think, he needs to get stuck in order for the time to add up to be enough to skim through [Accelerated C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/) and be able to understand most of what he comes across (not for being able to write such code, mind you) without asking?

Comment: @sbi: Of course asking should be the last ressort solution, when no other option exists. Reading and practicing are indeed much more efficient in the long run.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`void Blah<BOARD>::Generate(SgPoint p)`

`Generate` is a member function of a [class template](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates) `Blah` .

`BOARD` is the name of the parameter.

Your class `Blah` could be like this :

```
template <typename BOARD>
class Blah
{
   //...some code
   void Generate(SgPoint p);
   //...some more code
};
```

Answer (score 7):

`Blah` is most likely a templated class, `Generate` is a method from this class and this is most likely the first line of the method definition.

Edit: Oh and `BOARD` is the template parameter (can be type or integral value).

Comment: `<sigh>` It's a _class template_. There's no template classes.

Comment: @sbi Your are right that it's not a template class. But that's not what I wrote.

Comment: I'm sorry. In my defense I can say I'm correcting someone on this almost daily here. That's probably why my pattern matcher incorrectly pavloved on your answer...

Answer (score 5):

This is the `Generate` method of the `Blah` [class template](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/) specialized for template parameter `BOARD`.

In other words, what follows is the actual code that gets called when the `Blah` template is used to process an instance of class `BOARD`.

Other classes may get processed in a different way if separate specializations exist for them, or via the default non-specialized implementation of `Generate`, or not at all if there is no default and no specialization for them - in which case, an attempt to call that function will not compile.

There is a short introduction to the topic of template specialization [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/template_specialization.html).

Comment: Note that `BOARD` might be a template parameter, too, if Mick omitted the `template< typename BOARD >`.

Answer (score 3):

You run into [C++ templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_%28programming%29) - very neat feature!